# Gateway differs between Ethernet and Wi-Fi

Tags: router, routing, troubleshooting, modem, gateway

*Preface: I am somewhat of a noob in networking and couldn't find an answer anywhere else. Recently I started having problems with my fiber optic broadband. Some torrents from a specific private site stopped working while some others were OK. Sometimes they work for a minute or two, but then the download drops. Upload seemed to be working, but after changing port in uTorrent and adding port forwards in router settings, that dropped as well. I hadn't set any port forwarding before at all and everything was working fine. It's not working on Wi-Fi either. But before adding port forwarding I noticed that I couldn't access my router's setting by its default IP address while using an Ethernet cable. So -*

**Suddenly, my default gateway while using Ethernet has changed from 192.168.1.254 to 62.85.20.1. If I switch to Wi-Fi, it's back to old-correct one. I suspect that this may be related to problems I've been having. Can it? I did reset my router with no changes. Honestly, I do not understand what this really means - how can they differ?**

If this helps in any way, the router/modem is Alcatel-Lucent I-240W-A.
IP addresses are allocated dynamically.

`ipconfig` when using Ethernet:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : apollo.lv
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7d45:18f4:fb92:20ca%2
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 62.85.21.189
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 62.85.20.1

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

`ipconfig` with WiFi:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : apollo.lv

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Wireless LAN adapter WiFi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::69cc:847f:5204:36fd%9
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 4:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cringed at this a little.  You didn't do port forwarding, you put your computer in the DMZ, (De-Militarized Zone).  Basically ALL traffic is able to to hit your computer when you're on Ethernet.  GET OFF ETHERNET RIGHT NOW!!!

Posting to get the last bit out to you, more to come.

Edit:
In an nutshell, try to undo everything you did to get things back the way they were.  Disable DMZ and any port forwarding you did and see if you get a 192.168.X.X address again.

> Some torrents from a specific private site stopped working while some others were OK.

Chances are, you've used a large amount of bandwidth and your ISP has decided to throttle your speeds for specific traffic/sites.  If everything else is downloading at regular speeds, then your ISP is only throttling your torrenting.  If you want to try and get the speed back up, you'll need to <del>buy whatever it is you're pirating</del> use a VPN service so that the ISP can't see what type of traffic you're using.  Mind you, at a certain point, your ISP may just throttle your speed altogether.  You agreed to in the TOS and AUP that was signed before the service was started.  Some VPN services might have a free trial that you can use to see if you get faster speeds again.  I haven't had a need for a VPN service in a while, so I don't know what all will be in the market.

Comment: I did not. Only added port forwarding. See http://prntscr.com/frt5lc - had one rule for each WAN & LAN. It seems that you have misunderstood me. Default gateway changed before I had done anything. I am 100% sure that my ISP is not throttling my speeds.

Comment: The 62.85.X.X IP address is not a reserved IP address, so instead of enabling the DMZ, you may have somehow enabled bridged mode instead.  Still just as bad since the traffic is going directly to your computer.  The IP address is possibly somewhere in the Riga, Latvia area from what Ripe.net is telling me.  Under your Security tab, look for "DMZ and ALG" and see if the DMZ check box is checked.  Under Network and LAN, make sure everything is set to Route mode, not bridged.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/fswfbi Switched from 4th to 1st LAN port. I refuse to believe that it has been in bridged mode all the time... I didn't have such problems before. DMZ & ALG were off. Thanks!